# EF Core "The instance of entity type 'X' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key..."

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

So I am getting the following error message:

> The instance of entity type 'X' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {...} is already being tracked

This happens when we merge a collection of sub items. Back in EF 6 the following pattern would work fine:

```
dbContext.Items.RemoveRange(owner.Items);
owner.Items = newItems.Select(i => dbContext.Items.Add(new Item(i)).ToList();
```

In EF Core this does not work for items with composite key. My guess is that the removed items are marked for deletion but are still tracked. So when new ones with matching composite key are **added**, SaveChanges() fails because there are 2 entities being tracked with the same identifier.

So, is it safe to assume the above pattern should no longer be used and instead properly merge items using a full outer join for example?

Or, is there a way to make it still work like back in EF 6?

Comment: This doesn't work in EF6 either, except for many-to-many relationship with implicit junction table, which as you know is not supported in EF Core (yet). So yes, you need to merge them manually. Or use some external package like [AutoMapper.Collections](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection) or [Detached.EntityFramework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/#detachedentityframework) etc.

Comment: Yes, it only works with many-to-many in EF6. And thank you for the links.